# How Set local storage to 0 if undefined?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
if localStorage["BestScore"] = undefined;
{
localStorage["BestScore"]=0; 
maxScore=0;
}

 var maxScore=localStorage["BestScore"]; 
  var newScore=false
  function drawScore(score) {
    if (newScore == true && score < maxScore) {
      newScore = false;
    }
    if (score > maxScore) {
      newScore = true;
      localStorage["BestScore"] = score;
      if ([5, 10, 15, 20].indexOf(score) !== -1) {
        play(sndMedal);
      } else { 
        play(sndGain);
      }
    }
```

> This code is to set the max score and then store it but it doesn't seem to set the local storage to 0 if undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However if you need to check a variable against `undefined` value, there is no need to invent any special method, since JavaScript has a `typeof` operator, which is simple, fast and cross-platform:

```
if (typeof localStorage["BestScore"] === "undefined") {
    localStorage["BestScore"] = 0;
}
```

It returns a string indicating the type of the variable or other unevaluated operand. The main advantage of this method, compared to `if (value === undefined) { ... }`, is that `typeof` will never raise an exception in case if variable `value` does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
if localStorage["BestScore"] = undefined;
```

should be:

```
if( typeof localStorage["BestScore"] === 'undefined' )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if localStorage["BestScore"] = undefined;
```

should be `==`

else you are assigning, not comparing.

Answer (score 0):

use `==` or `===` as a comparison operator, then it should be fine